# Android Studio Chipmunk not generating singed AAB files

Tags: android, android-studio, android-app-bundle

Since updating to Android Studio Chipmunk I am no longer able to generate signed AAB files. I'm not getting any errors, Android Studio just doesn't do anything. I select the menu item "Generate signed package / APK" -> I select Android App Bundle -> I specify the key store (already used successfully in the past) -> then I select the Release option and press the Finish button ... but absolutely nothing happens. Like the build request is ignored. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you have started using new **Android Studio Chipmunk** and trying to updated your android application (version 1) that was previously developed using Android Studio only; have signed (E.g. with `Key store & Key alias`) and published to Play Store, now at present you wanted to update or release a new version (called version 2) of previously developed application using new Android Studio Chipmunk and generating new signed build via **same** `Key store & Key alias`.

As far as I knew, it is "`know issue`" with Android Studio Chipmunk. Actually Android Studio Chipmunk does **not** consider different-different password for both `Key store & Key alias`. It is only consider same password for `Key store & Key alias`.

Comment: I have the same password for both. Thanks for your answer anyway

Comment: did you tried with old applications to update in play store with old keys that was having different-different password?

Comment: No, I didn't. unfortunately it's not something I can test right now

Answer (score -1):

You need to select the right key from the `key alias` dropdown. While generating the signed build from the `Generate Signed build or APK` dialog, click on the icon next to the `key alias` field:

[image]

Then select the right key which you had used previously:

[image]

click `OK` and then `Next`. Select the right `Build variant` and click the `Finish` button. You should see the build happening.

Comment: I had already a private/public key that worked before the AS update. What you propose it is standard procedure not a fix. I know how to sign a AAB. Thanks

Comment: @Sergiob I was also facing this problem after upgrading to Chipmunk, but after selecting the right key fixed my problem. You can also try by creating a new key from the same keystore file (`.jks`)

Comment: As I said, it doesn't work for me

Comment: Weird thing, but re-selecting alias, worked perfectly for me. Thanks